# Como ir buscar mensagens de A para B e de B para A na mesma query?

Tags: mysql

Tenho um `SELECT` que faz quase exatamente o que preciso, é um sistema de chat (inbox) semelhante ao facebook. Então ele me mostra com todos os contatos que tenho uma conversa, porém me trás a última mensagem e a data.

O meu problema é o seguinte, se eu envio uma mensagem para alguém pela primeira vez e esta pessoa não me responde não aparece.

Eu sei onde está o problema é onde peço para mostrar apenas as mensagens que eu recebi, porém não sei como resolver isso para que mesmo que eu não receba uma resposta, a mensagem fique lá. 
Enfim, acho que consegui explicar, segue o `SELECT` e a estrutura da minha tabela:

Tabela

```
user_inbox_id (id)
user_inbox_from (quem enviou)
user_inbox_to (quem recebeu)
user_inbox_msg (mensagem)
user_inbox_date (data)
user_inbox_new (mostra se foi lida ou nao)
```

Select

```
SELECT * FROM user_inbox ta, 
(SELECT user_inbox_to, user_inbox_from, max(user_inbox_date) ultima_msg 
FROM user_inbox
GROUP BY user_inbox_to, user_inbox_from) um, user

WHERE 
ta. user_inbox_to = um.user_inbox_to 
AND ta.user_inbox_from = um.user_inbox_from
AND ta.user_inbox_date = um.ultima_msg
AND ta.user_inbox_to = '$user_id'
AND ta.user_inbox_from = user.user_id
ORDER BY user_inbox_date DESC
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Não entendi o seu problema amigo, poderia explicar-se melhor?

Comment: Olá! Meu problema é o seguinte, este SELECT só está trazendo mensagens quando eu recebo, quando eu envio mensagem ele não está trazendo, por conta desta linha **AND ta.user_inbox_to = '$user_id'** porem, removendo ela o select não fonciona... Ou seja esse inbox to é quem recebe, eu preciso nesse select dizer que tambem quero que ele verifique as mensagens que eu enviei, no caro seria a coluna **user_inbox_from = '$user_id'**, ficou mais claro amigo?

Comment: Se eu entendi bem, você quer tanto as mensagens que o usuário A mandou pro B, quanto as que o B mandou pro A, tudo na mesma *query*. É isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema é que estas a ir buscar as mensagens enviadas, para buscar as recebidas basta fazeres assim:

```
SELECT * FROM user_inbox ta, 
(SELECT user_inbox_to, user_inbox_from, max(user_inbox_date) ultima_msg 
FROM user_inbox
GROUP BY user_inbox_to, user_inbox_from) um, user

WHERE 
ta. user_inbox_to = um.user_inbox_to 
AND ta.user_inbox_from = um.user_inbox_from
AND ta.user_inbox_date = um.ultima_msg
AND ((ta.user_inbox_to = '$user_id' AND ta.user_inbox_from = user.user_id ) OR (ta.user_inbox_to = user.user_id AND ta.user_inbox_from = '$user_id'))
ORDER BY user_inbox_date DESC
```

Assim com os dois utilizadores em questão consegues ir buscar as enviadas e recebidas por esses dois utilizadores nos dois sentidos.

Comment: Perfeito amigo! Muito obrigado pela sua ajuda!

Comment: De nada Leonardo